# Json data not loading quick enough to render a dynamic form

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-promise

A few months ago I followed the Angular2 CookBook recipe for Dynamic Forms. Everything was going great in my Angular2/Ionic2 App, until a few days ago my code was busting at the seams.

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.doLoadQuestions();
    this.leadsForm = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions)

  };

doLoadQuestions(){
    this.jsondata.load().then((data) => {
      this.questionsFromJSON = data
      this.questions = this.qs.doGetQuestion(this.questionsFromJSON)
      this.leadsForm = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions)
    }).then(() =>{
        this.doReceiveValues();
        this.ems.doGenerateFormErrorObject(this.questionsFromJSON, this.formError);
        this.doGenerateAllBiscuitArray(this.questionsFromJSON);
        this.doGenerateDisplayController();
    }) 
      // I had to load/generate the form in this method, otherwise an error occurs in console
      // It would be best if this was moved out of here, but for now it must stay in for it to work.

  };
```

Time to refactor...

The first thing that bothers me is the long method, when I try to take out `this.questions = this.qs.doGetQuestion(this.questionsFromJSON)` or any of the methods in the second .then() call, and place them into ngOnInit I get an error. "Can not read 'length' of undefined".

What I tried:

1. Placing console.logs everywhere to see when the data from
   jsondata.load() is being brought into my component. It seems to be
   successfully loaded after the ngOnInit `this.leadsForm =
   this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions)`
2. Difference combinations of ngOnInit, calling methods in constructor, ngOnChanges, and placing the jsondata.load method in a service. None of them seemed to make a difference.

The other thing you may have noticed is the second call of the `this.leadsForm = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions)` in ngOnInit(). If I take this out, I get the same error as before, "Can not read 'length' of undefined".

Im stuck, and I am trying to make my code much more modular, but this is the first step into my component and everything is dependent on this method.

Maybe I should just leave it the way it is, but as it stands, its very inflexible and to me, clunky.

Thanks for any help

Comment: where are you taking the length of something (maybe somewhere in the HTML template or in another part of the component file:  `<object or variable>.length`)?

Comment: Thats the thing, I have received this error multiple times, and every time the methods in the stacktrace never contain an explicit .length. I wonder if the .length error has something to do with .forEach, because they tend to coincide.